# db2 issue selecting dynamically from an unknown table

Tags: select, db2, execute

I need a store procedure that loop in a table that returns a name of a table in the db2 and depending from that name i need to do a select statement from the named table. i have tried doing it with an 'execute immediate' in so many ways that a lost the count here is an example of the execute immediate:

```
set insertstring = 'INSERT INTO pribpm.TEMP_T_TOQUE_CICLO (idSemana,tiempo_ciclo,tiempo_toque) 
SELECT  to_number(to_char( '''|| ' time_stamp ' ||'''  ,' || ' IW ' || ')) ,SUM(KPITOTALTIMECLOCK),SUM(s.KPIEXECUTIONTIMECLOCK) FROM ' ||  TABLA  || ' where     to_number(to_char( '''|| ' time_stamp ' ||''' ,' || ' IW ' || ')) between  ' ||     (to_number(to_char(FECHA,'IW'))-3) || ' and  ' || to_number(to_char(FECHA,'IW')) || ' GROUP     BY  to_number(to_char('''|| ' time_stamp ' ||''' ,'  || ' IW ' || '))';    
PREPARE stmt FROM insertstring; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insertstring;
```

where tabla is a string that contains the name of the table and fecha is a date in timestamp type

besides i've tried it with cursors like this

```
set select_ = 'SELECT time_stamp, KPITOTALTIMECLOCK, KPIEXECUTIONTIMECLOCK FROM ' || tabla;
PREPARE stmt FROM select_;
FOR v2 AS
c2 cursor for
execute select_ 
do    
if to_number(to_char(time_stamp,'IW')) between 
     (to_number(to_char(fecha,'IW'))-3) and to_number(to_char(fecha,'IW'))  then
--something here
end if;
END FOR;
```

but with no success.

may you or may someone please help me clear my error or giving some other idea about this im trying to do?
all this in db2 environment

Answer (score 0):

Write a procedure and loop tables from SYSCAT.TABLES to get the table name and again loop to fire a select query for each and every table.

I am not 100% sure as it has been a long time I worked on db2